# Ng-model with button

Tags: angularjs

Good morning, I make a loop to catch "name " in an array and each "name " has variables with information. I need the ng -model receive the value of the "name " when I click on the "button" to oh yes I can make a loop in this "name".

```
div class="list-group" ng-repeat="rep in list.report">
 <button type="button" class="list-group-item " ng-model="ctrl.x">
       {{rep.name}}
        </button></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, is this what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/3ajtoyfm/

Angular

```
function Controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.rep = null;
  vm.reps = [{
    name: 'Jimmy Page',
    band: 'Led Zeppelin'
  }, {
    name: 'Ozzy Osbourne',
    band: 'Black Sabbath'
  }, {
    name: 'Trent Reznor',
    band: 'NIN'
  }];
  vm.getRep = getRep;

  function getRep(rep) {
    vm.rep = rep;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button ng-repeat="rep in ctrl.reps" ng-click="ctrl.getRep(rep)">{{rep.name}}</button>
<br>
<div ng-if="ctrl.rep">
  <h4>
     Rep
     </h4> {{ctrl.rep.name}} - {{ctrl.rep.band}}
</div>
```

Comment: I made a change in the controller in the variable reps   [https://jsfiddle.net/3ajtoyfm/7/]

Comment: Hmm, don't you want the report to be an object?

Comment: I could not understand

Answer (score 0):

ng-model won't work with the button use ng-click :

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="rep in list.report">
   <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-click="ctrl.x = rep.name">
   {{rep.name}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm already using ng -click it to view input if it click the button

Comment: <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="rep in list.report">
                                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item " ng-model="ctrl.x=" style="width:450px;height:35px" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
                                        {{rep.name}}
                                    </button>

Comment: You can have multiple statement i think : ng-click="ctrl.x = rep.name;showDetails = !showDetails". Otherwise create a function in your controller and perform what you need in the function.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this